# URL Rewriting - Redirect With No File Extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, friendly-url, url-rewriting

I am currently using the following rules in a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

This works well to ensure that `/myfile.php` works as well as just `myfile` (with no extension in the URL). It also handles querystrings with no problems, so `myfile?var=foo` also works.

The problem is that these are registering in Google Analytics as being two separate files. So while `myfile.php` might be the third most popular page on my site, with X visits, `myfile` might be the fifth most popular page on my site with Y visits.

How can I do a hard redirect, rather than "accept either one" type of rule?

Answer (score 2):

Try this rule to redirect requests for `.php` files:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(([^/?]*/)*[^/?]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^.+\.php$ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I added this in between the first and second lines. It appears to have not made any effect.

Comment: So if you request “/foo/bar.php” you are not being redirected to “/foo/bar”?

Comment: No, it's still loading /foo/bar.php
I also had to move the closing bracket, as it would cut out a directory when used in certain folders.

Answer (score 2):

Could you just change your last RewriteRule to do this?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,R=301]
```

That will redirect "myfile" to "myfile.php".

Also, you can adjust for this inside of Google Analytics using rules as well.  Although that probably isn't an ideal solution.

**ETA**: If you want myfile.php to redirect to myfile, try this for your last rule instead:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This makes the .php page stay as .php. The page with no extension goes from:
http://localhost/2008/about/management
to
http://localhost/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Group/Apache2/htdocs/2008/about/management.php

Comment: Isn't that what you were looking for?  Or did you want "myfile.php" to redirect to just "myfile"?

Comment: Yes, myfile.php to myfile...but it shouldn't be adding in C:/Program Files etc etc into my URL. That creates an invalid path.

Comment: Yikes, not sure why it would it be adding C:/Program Files to your URL.. Maybe you need a "RewriteBase /" in there?

Comment: I'm looking as well for this answer and cannot find it anywhere. I get the same non-functional results as @CoryDee.

Answer (score 1):

You could just put in your pages a

```
<link rel="canonical" href="..." />
```

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Took me a few hours...but I believe I have finally found the answer.

```
// The Original
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

// Add This
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.#?\ ]+\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.php /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Found here: http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3961636.htm