# Is there a way to redirect traffic from file extension

Tags: html, .htaccess

I currently have the piece of code that allows you to go to one of the pages on my site without having to type in the file extension in the url. I am wondering if there is a way to redirect all traffic from users using the file extension in the link, to the link without a file extension. For example, if a user types example.com/about.html I want it to redirect it to example.com/about.

Comment: which web server are you using? For Apache you can use mod_rewrite.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do post examples of your current code and expected things in your question and let us know then.

Comment: The answer to your question is: certainly that is possible.

Comment: would you happen to have the code for it that I would put in the htaccess file?

Comment: “url rewrite from file name extension to no extension” typed into Google, leads to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681322/url-rewriting-redirect-with-no-file-extension or https://htaccessbook.com/add-remove-change-file-extensions-htaccess/ in no time. For the future, please replace your “I am wondering” approach, with a bit of actual basic research.

Comment: I just need a line of code to go in my .htaccessthat will redirect users that type in example.com/about.html to example.com/about. As an example